# When does ActiveRecord run queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm interested in when ActiveRecord runs it's queries because I remember reading that Rails will optimize queries by not executing them until the actual data is used, I'm just not sure how I can prove this or find it in documentation. I can't just run the lines in rails console because that will explicitly run the query when I type it in. I'll explain what I mean below:

```
@stores = Store.where(active: true)
# Query should not have ran yet

@stores = @stores.includes(:owners)
# Query should not have ran yet

@stores.each { |store| store.do_something }
# So from this point forward, it should run
# Store.includes(:owners).where(active: true) all at once
# or it would have ran 3 queries instead of one.
```

How can I prove this or can someone lead me to the correct documentation?

Comment: Typically it executes the query once you try to access the data via a method like `find`, `each`, etc. I couldn't find a definitive list on these methods. I believe the rule of thumb is to know whether the method you're calling returns an active record or a relation.

Answer (score 0):

While I know that Rails defers executing queries until they are actually needed, I haven't gotten into that part in the documentation. To figure out how many db queries are ran, I use this gem called [db-query-matchers](https://github.com/brigade/db-query-matchers) in my RSpec tests for experiments.

In your case I would do something similar to this:

```
it 'experiment 1' do
  expect { @stores = Store.where(active: true) }.to make_database_queries(count: 0..3)
end

it 'experiment 2' do
  expect do 
    @stores = Store.where(active: true) 
    @stores = @stores.includes(:owners)
  end.to make_database_queries(count: 0..3)
end

it 'experiment 3' do
  expect do 
    @stores = Store.where(active: true) 
    @stores = @stores.includes(:owners)
    @stores.each { |store| store.do_something }
  end.to make_database_queries(count: 0..3)
end
```

Comment: Interesting way to calculate queries. I've been trying to count them in the rails server log. Is there a way in the dev environment to count them or assign the query count for later output?

Comment: Not sure, it's a matcher for RSpec, so it's more of for the test environment rather than dev. I guess [`@counter`](https://github.com/brigade/db-query-matchers/blob/master/lib/db_query_matchers/make_database_queries.rb) can be exposed?